Using Nakayama's lemma in non-local ring
Let $R$ be a Noetherian integral domain of dimension one and $\mathfrak{m}$ an ideal such that $\text{dim }\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2=1$ as an $R/\mathfrak{m}$-vector space. The localization of $R$ at $\mathfrak{m}$ is a local ring and should define a valuation on $R$'s field of fractions. I want to construct the valuation function directly for $R$. Let $\text{ord }x=\sup \{d:x\in\mathfrak{m}^d\}$. Then if $k$ is the field of fractions I could define $v(f/g)=\text{ord }f-\text{ord }g$. It is easy to prove that if $\text{ord }$ is well-defined as a valuation function, then so is $v$. So I have to show that $\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty\mathfrak{m}^j=0$ and $\text{ord }fg=\text{ord }f+\text{ord }g$. If I was arguing in $R_\mathfrak{m}$ I would use Nakayama's lemma to lift the basis of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ as a vector space to a generating set for $\mathfrak{m}$. Is a similar move possible in $R$?

For any Noetherian domain $R$ and any proper ideal $I$ of $R$, $\cap_{j=1}^{\infty} I^{j} = 0$. This can be deduced as a consequence of a nontrivial result about completions - see, for example, Corollary 10.18 in Atiyah-Macdonald.

@AlexWertheim Thank you.
